# select from large number of options

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a select field in html. This field will have values from 1 to 27 to select. So i want to try some some sort method rather than typing manually for 27 values. Is it possible with the help of java script or something? I am not an expert in front end technologies so be generous please.

Comment: I wouldn't do this with JavaScript. You'll have to type the values either way.

Comment: Are you trying to list numbers 1 to 27 in a dropdown list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are trying to list 1 to 27 in dropdown or trying to simply list 27 items. In either case these are both. This is using basic JavaScript.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0zy7655z/

Lists 27 times

```
var vals = ['item1','item2','item3','etc.'];
var sel1 = document.getElementById('list1');
vals.forEach(function(val,ind) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.text = val;
  opt.value = ind;
  sel1.appendChild(opt);
});
```

Lists 1 to 27

```
var sel2 = document.getElementById('list2');
for (var i = 1; i <= 27; i++) {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.text = i;
  opt.value = i;
  sel2.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Comment: I prefer your pure JS over the way I mentioned. +1

Answer (score 1):

Well, you CAN if you want to...

The HTML

```
<select id="mySelect" name="mySelect"></select>
```

Pure Javascript:

var values = ['something', 'something else', 'some other thing'];
var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelect');

```
for (var i=values.length;i--;){
  var optionElem = document.createElement('option');
  optionElem.setAttribute('value', value[i]);
  var optionText = document.createTextNode(value[i]);
  optionElem.appendChild(optionTect);
  mySelect.appendChild(optionElem);
}
```

Or you could use jQuery:

```
var values = ['something', 'something else', 'some other thing'];

    $.each(values, function(idx, value) {
        var optionElem = '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
        $('#mySelect').append(optionElem);
    });
```

Still this is usually a silly thing to do unless you need them to be dynamically generated.